# How to leave out empty values in queries?

Tags: sqlplus

I'm trying to place these values into one column, but sometimes there is no value for 'County'. How can I make it that It doesn't show up as Name_of_town, , Postcode?

```
SQL> select SuppName || ', ' || Street || ', ' || Town || ', ' || County || ', ' || PostCode AS "Supplier Address"
2  from Suppliers
3  ORDER BY 1;
```

This is what I currently get back from the query. (Example of ',' by itself is on the first query result)

```
Supplier Address
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Systems Ltd., 155 Stradleigh Place, London, , E10 6LL
Fastorder Stationers, Riverside View, Newport, Gwent, NP1  7XJ
I.T. Supplies (Wales), 3 Marlborough Ave., Cardiff, , CF1  1IT
Legal Services Ltd., Westway Road, London, , N8  8PA
Office Matters, 20 Berrick Street, Bridgend, Mid Glam., CF38 3BB
TKG Tools Ltd., 7 High Street, Swansea, , SA7  2WG
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Oracle's NVL is the way to go. It will replavce null values with a string of your choosing. I am assuming when you say there is no value for County, that field contains `null`. Otherwice oracle [REPLACE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) would work.

[NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm)

Try this:

```
select SuppName || ', ' || Street || ', ' || Town || ', ' || NVL(County, 'No_County') || ', ' || PostCode AS "Supplier Address"
from Suppliers
ORDER BY 1;
```